# How to get index value of same array value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Now i have an array `var a = [4,7,4]` in this array value 4 is same values and how can i get the index of same value.

I got some code in StackOverflow but its checking only num 2 value, i need to check every element and **return index value**.

***JS:***

```
var dataset = [2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8];
var results = [];
for ( i=0; i < dataset.length; i++ ){
    if ( dataset[i] == 2 ){
        results.push( i );
    }
}

return results;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/friendz/42y08384/15/)

http://jsfiddle.net/friendz/42y08384/15/

Comment: Instead of just taking code that you clearly don't understand, perhaps you should try learning some javascript? Just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29437996-copying-and-pasting-from-stack-overflow

Comment: Last 1 week  im learning JavaScript and tried but i didnt get it. thanks bro

Comment: What is your desired output from `[2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8]`?

Comment: @toraz.. [2,3,2] in this array 2  are some duplicate values i need output index values 0,2

Comment: So your desired output is an array of all the indexes of wherever the **first** element of the array occurs?

Comment: @toraz.  Actually i have only three arrays a = [4,7,4] its dynamically changing every time. i didn't want all index i need only same value index. In this array output  index 0 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to build a lookup:

```
const out = dataset.reduce((p, c, i) => {

  // if the current value doesn't exist as a
  // key in the object, add it and assign it an
  // empty array
  p[c] = (p[c] || []);

  // push the index of the current element to its
  // associated key array
  p[c].push(i);
  return p;
}, {});
```

OUTPUT

```
{
  "2": [0, 1, 3],
  "4": [2, 5],
  "6": [4],
  "7": [6],
  "8": [7]
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4195feaL/)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

```
var dataset = [2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8];
var results = [];
for ( i=0; i < dataset.length; i++ ){
    for(j=i+1;j<dataset.length;j++){
    if ( dataset[i] == dataset[j] ){
        results.push( j );
        break;
    } 
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

The logic behind this code is check every value with other values of array so that duplicate values' index can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sur to understand what you want. The code bellow give you all index per value in the dataset.

### Output :

[image]

### Code

```js
var dataset = [2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8];
var results = {};

for ( i=0; i < dataset.length; i++ )
{
    if (typeof results[dataset[i]] === 'undefined')
    {
   results[dataset[i]] = [];
    }
 
    results[dataset[i]].push(i); 
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copy this code and see on console.log**

```js
console.log(Array.from({length: 50}, (v,i) => i));
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, here you can see : http://jsfiddle.net/42y08384/18/

```
var dataset = [2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8];
var results = {};
dataset.forEach(function(item, key) {
    if(!results[item]) {
    results[item] = [];
  }


  console.log(key)  
  results[item].push(key);
});

//results is an object where the key is the value from the dataset and the array within is the indexes where you can find them
for(key in results) {
    console.log('Value ' + key + ' can be found in position '+ results[key].join(', ') )
}
```